# Different front page for logged in and logged out user but the same URL in Wordpress

Tags: frontpage, home-url

I have two home pages created in WP. One is set as the front page but for only logged-out users. For logged-in users, they see home page 2 as their home page.

However, I want the URL for logged-in users to be the default URL of my site. So a mere redirection doesn't work as I will have "site.com/home-2".

Is there a way I could achieve this? The code below came across doesn't work and breaks my site.

```
unction switch_homepage() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $page = 2516; // for logged in users
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    } else {
        $page = 2; // for logged out users
        update_option( 'page_on_front', $page );
        update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'switch_homepage' );

?>
```

Comment: Hmm...maybe it's easier to make if statement on that page to check if user is logged in and display different layout deppending on result of this check. Maybe using get_template_part() function for example)

Comment: Using `update_option()` to change the settings will change it for *every* user, not just the user who's viewing the page right now. This solution isn't the way to go.

Comment: Yes, using the update_option() to change the settings doesn't work and shows a totally different page as the front page when I log in as a guest. All I am trying to do is to make sure that whatever my frontpage is for both the logged in user and logged out user is the url stays thesame.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to display different content to logged-in vs. logged-out users, I'd recommend using the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_387084_content_selector' );
function wpse_387084_content_selector( $content ) {
    if ( is_front_page() && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $page = get_post( 2516 );
        $content = $page->post_content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

The above code assumes that you've set the "Page on Front" to the page with ID `2`, and that's what you want to show to unauthenticated users.

Comment: Thank you Pat J but this didn't work for me.

Comment: I am using a buddyboss theme and have the activities page for logged-in users set as the home page. But I want it to assume the default site url as its own URL withouth the forward slash just like the homepage for logged-out users.